# Executing a query on a decision table at run time in IBM wodm 8.0

Tags: ilog, jrules

Hope you all are doing good!
My requirement is -
I have a decision table having hundreds of records, from front end application let's say .net or bpm users enters some data and based on this input data I want to fire a dynamic automated query (with the values entered by user) on the decision table which should return me let's say 15 or more records and then I want to keep firing different queries on the resultset until I have filtered it out to just one record.

Could someone please help me on how this can be done ? Appreciate all your help.

Thanks,
Rao

Comment: Hi, can you explain more? what do you mean by 'execute a query' ?
You can do a loop to your task (if resulSet>1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry brother, this is not possible since a decision table is nothing but a RuleSet with if-then rules unlike a Database table. You cannot use a DT to store you data.

DT is not for data storage rather to take a decision.